# How should I transfer dynamic data updates from MainActivity to a Fragment without making fragment methods static?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have implemented a REST api (using Retrofit2, probably irrelevant) called within MainActivity. I have stored the results in a private fields within MainActivity. One example snippet:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
private String mSystemName;
mSystemName = response.body().getName();
```

From MainActivity I pass the fields as paramaters to the methods of a fragment (setup with a NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController) where they will be displayed. E.g.

```
HomeFragment.setName(mSystemName);
```

In my fragment I have:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
public static void setName(String name){
    homeViewModel.SetName(name);
}
```

If I don't make setName static then I get an error "non-static method setName(String) cannot be referenced from a static context". Although not explicit, I presume that MainActivity is static by definition?

I've got to one where I can't make it static as within the method there are references within the Android libraries that are non-static methods, e.g.

```
TextView(getActivity())
```

Have I got my way of transferring information between MainActivity (where I am doing the work of getting data from a remote system) to the fragment (to be displayed) wrong?

I can think of a number of different ways of cutting this (but I'm not sure any or which of these would be the recommended approach):

1. Do the work in the fragment, but I might later want different views in different fragments so it makes sense that I am doin the data collection in MainActivity.
2. Store the data differently and somehow trigger the fragment to update itself, ideally when the data changes, but it could also be with some call.
3. Send the data to the fragment, but rather than sending it to the method that needs to display it, have the fragment realise it needs to do that once the data is stored. This would be a bit like my MainActivity has an onSharedPreferenceChanged listener for the user changing settings.
4. Get the fragment to request the data from the MainActivity (but I thought fragements were supposed to not rely on the MainActivity, although this seems to be the most requested question related to mine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send data to fragment from activity via using bundle:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("exampleDataKey", "exampleDataValue");
HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
homeFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

Fragment onCreateView method:

```
String exampleDataValue = getArguments().getString("exampleDataKey");
```

Comment: What if I don't justwant to do it when the fragment is created, but at a regular interval after the fragment is visible I want to update the values?

Comment: You can use live data for this : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata